Is it possible connect to azure storage from AWS hosted snowflake account?
We are trying to create a storage integration to use azure storage and for that, we need to add snowflake vnet/subnet in azure as our firewall blocks all public traffic.
But as it's hosted in AWS, we are getting only the VPC ids & not subnet details with "SELECT SYSTEM$GET_SNOWFLAKE_PLATFORM_INFO();"
{Following this docu
Is there a way to have a one time set up for using azure storage in this situation? (Do not wanna go with SAS token)
Tried to find aws public ip range for that region to allow those. But that is expected to change as frequently as several times a week.
